# Deciphering handwritten phrase and its meaning

Tags: handwriting

In the [前回の僕街 series](http://bokumachi-anime.com/special/zenkainobokumachi/), we see sketches drawn by the director of the 僕だけがいない街 anime that are generally humorous rewrites of a scene in the previous episode.

[image: 前回の僕街 第九話]

In the ninth sketch (image above), we see Satoru chasing after the car in the foreground after Kayo is taken away to protective custody with her grandmother.

I can read the first two phrases, but the last one is hard to read:

> Kayo's grandmother: あの子、まだ走ってるよ
>   Kayo: 先生、スピード上げて
>   Yashiro-sensei: (ネラーイ)?

Is this right? Even then, what does it mean? I can't seem to make sense of 狙い in this context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not ネ, that's オー.  See, there's a single vertical line all the way through it, and the ー looks like a ー.

Fluent readers use context in reading, and can often read words even if a let_er is missing.  The more words you learn, the more your brain will be able to match patterns accurately, regardless of how they're written.  In this case, if you know the colloquial borrowing オーライ 'all right', then you should be able to recognize オーラーイ♪ here as being the same word with emphatic lengthening.

Comment: I had a feeling I was off because of the vertical stroke as you mentioned, but didn't realise the stroke on the right was separate!